# Cucumber ExtentReport generation with TestNG during multiple thread execution

Tags: java, multithreading, cucumber, testng, extentreports

I'm running tests in parallel on mobile devices using Cucumber and TestNG. My TestNG runner class is given below.

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features="src/test/resources/features",
        glue={"org.cucumber.stepdefs"},
        plugin = {
        "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:" }, monochrome = true)

public class TestRunner extends BaseTest {

    private static TestNGCucumberRunner testRunner;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUP() {   
        System.out.println("Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - object hash = " + this.hashCode());
        testRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(TestRunner.class);
        ExtentProperties extentProperties = ExtentProperties.INSTANCE;
        extentProperties.setReportPath("output/" + this.hashCode() + "-report.html");
    }

    @Test(description="Tests",dataProvider="features")
    public void setUpClass(CucumberFeatureWrapper cFeature) {
        testRunner.runCucumber(cFeature.getCucumberFeature());
    }

    @DataProvider(name="features")
    public Object[][] getFeatures() {
        return testRunner.provideFeatures();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void teardown() {
        testRunner.finish();
    }

}
```

Which is working as expected - my Cucumber tests are run in parallel on separate threads for each connected device (defined in my testng.xml file).

I'm using ExtentReports to generate reports after each run, though at the moment i'm getting only a single report, where I would like a separate report for each running thread.

What I can't understand is why this is happening. I've added console prints to check if there is an instant of the TestRunner class for each running thread, and indeed there is - my console log after a run contains the following (assuming 2 mobile devices are connected):

```
Thread = 33 - object hash = 923219673
Thread = 32 - object hash = 280884709
```

So this is working as i expect, except when it comes to generating the report, only 1 report containing all the test data is created. I was under the assumption that because i am setting the report path to a unique file name in each thread in the `setUp()` method that a report for each thread should be created?

It seems that when it comes to generating the report that the Cucumber ExtendReport plugin waits for all tests to finish and generates a bulk report by default. Is this correct? And if so, how might i change this?

Below is the main part of my `pom.xml` file for additional configuration information.

```
<properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-java -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
         <version>4.2.0</version>
         <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-testng -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.5</version>
         <scope>compile</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-picocontainer -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.5</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
         <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
         <version>3.4.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
         <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
         <version>6.11</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
         <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
         <version>1.7.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
         <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
         <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.5</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
      <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
         <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
         <version>6.0.0-BETA3</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19</version>
            <configuration>
               <parallel>tests</parallel>
               <threadCount>10</threadCount>
               <suiteXmlFiles>
                  <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
               </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't mix different versions of cucumber.

Comment: I wasn't aware i was?

Comment: If version 4 is what you intend to use, there is an existing adapter which supports this out of box.  See https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter

Comment: Thanks @foursyth. Will give this a look. Does it support parallel report generation out of the box with no configuration what so ever?

Comment: Yes, it's the same for sequential and parallel, but version 4 only of Cucumber supports it.

Comment: @foursyth is there anywhere with an example on how to use this with TestNG? I'm running into multiple problems trying to use it.

Comment: @foursyth Ignore that last comment - it was an issue with Maven. I've got the adaptor working, though i still get a single html report containing all the tests in, rather than a separate report for each thread running in parallel. I can't seem to find anywhere on the GitHub that details about creating multiple individual reports during parallel test execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUP() {   
    System.out.println("Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + " - object hash = " + this.hashCode());
    testRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(TestRunner.class);
    ExtentProperties extentProperties = ExtentProperties.INSTANCE;
    extentProperties.setReportPath("output/" + this.hashCode() + "-report.html");
}
```

This setup method is invoked twice in parallel. It you are changing `setReportPath` on `ExtentProperties.INSTANCE` which is shared between these threads. So the threads are overwriting each others results. You can verify this by printing out the hash of `ExtentProperties.INSTANCE`.

Comment: how might i set the report path for each running thread without using ExtentProperties? I'm aware i can specify a path in the plugin options, but this can't be dynamically changed based on what thread is running.

Comment: I'd make two separate jobs in the CI system. Much less hassle.